# Raising numbers with powers

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, exponentiation

So the question is as follows:

> Let $f(x) = \int_{0}^x \frac{x}{2\sqrt{t}}dt$. Suppose $f(f(f(...f(f(a))...)))$ (done $2013$ times) $= 2^{2013}$. Find the real-valued solution of $a$

Now, for my solution:

Integrating $f(x)$, we get that:

$$f(x) = \left[x\sqrt{t}\right]_{0}^x = x\sqrt{x} = x^{3/2}$$

Now, by finding a pattern by continuously performing $f(f(a))$ $2013$ times, we get that:

$$x^{\left(3/2\right)^{2013}} = 2^{2013}$$

However, I was unable to determine an answer. In their solution it stated that:

$$x^{\left(3/2\right)^{2013}} = x^{\left(3/2\right)*{2013}}$$

It didn't say (which is the process I did):

$$x^{\left(3/2\right)^{2013}} = x^{\left(3^{2013}/2^{2013}\right)}$$

Now, which form is correct? Does the parenthesis change the way to evaluate the exponents?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are on right track. just take logs and get answer as $$\log x=2013\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{2013}\log 2$$

Comment: Also "their solution" is wrong as the relation $$a^{b^c}=a^{bc}$$ is **invalid.**

Comment: @Dr.MV: you are also making same mistake as "their solution".

Comment: @Dr.MV: If $f(x) = x^{3/2}$ then $$f(f(x)) = f(x^{3/2}) = (x^{3/2})^{3/2} = x^{9/4} = x^{((3/2)^{2})}$$ and similarly repeating 2013 times we get $$f(f(\cdots(x)\cdots)) = x^{((3/2)^{2013})}$$